# Google Cloud Platform Why if I declare a firewall rule it doesn't work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, firewall, platform

I has installed Debian Stretch as my OS in my VM instance. I has downloaded an installed (via git) the AllStarLink software to install it in the mentioned instance.

After installation and testing period, I run the VM instance and works fine. The application appears registered at allstarlink.org register server but -if I attempt to reach the application from outside- the system reject my connection.

I need the port 4569/udp to work with the application but after program several firewall rules, the instance still rejecting any connection from offside.

What is the right configuration for a firewall rule to permit my connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engine networks have some [implied rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) that block all incoming traffic with some [exceptions like SSH, RDP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) etc. and allow all outgoing traffic.

To allow traffic on a 4569 (or any other port than mentioned in the documentation) you have to [create a new firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) using GCP Console or [`gcloud` utility](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create).

In our case you have to specify

> You create or modify VPC firewall rules by using the Google Cloud
> Console, gcloud command-line tool, and REST API. When you create or
> modify a firewall rule, you can specify the instances to which it is
> intended to apply by using the target component of the rule.

Your `gcloud` command can look like this:

`gcloud compute --project=my-project-name firewall-rules create my-rule1 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:4569,udp:4569`

However you need to make sure that your instance also permits incoming traffic on that port ([by default Debian Stretch doesn't block anything](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall#Basic_software_for_network_traffic_manipulation). To make sure login to your VM and run this command: `sudo iptables -L`; you should see something like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This is default firewall configuration which means all traffic (on & out) is allowed.

Comment: I can apply your suggestion. The sudo iptables -L deliver it:

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:iax
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

I hope it works!

Comment: Were you able to create a firewall rule with `gcloud` ? Did it work ?